# error while configuring rest service between angular and node

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest, express, configuration

**Node Js :- app file**

```
var batch = require('./routes/batch');
app.use('/batch', batch);
```

**angular Js Rest request:-**

```
$scope.getBatchTransactionById = function(batchId){
        $http.get('/batch/:'+batchId).success(function (data) {
            $scope.gridOptions1.data = data;
        });        
    };
```

On running i am getting the below error:-

http://localhost:8080/batch/:23323 404 (Not Found)

I am not sure but its not routing to the batch folder , can anyone please help?

Comment: You don't need the colon (:). /batch/{id}

Can you also show your batch router/routes file?

Comment: Thanks, for the response, this is my batch file.var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/batch/:id', function(req, res, next) {
 console.log("Inside batch");
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

module.exports = router;  There is no logic inside this right no

Comment: Anyone can please help. Its for my academic project. Need to fix this asap.

Comment: You need to post your batch.js file so we can see what that's doing.

Comment: @Akash add that file to your question by editing it, if you can edit your question that is.